# How to AngularJS with WebSockets and JSON/RESTful APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, websocket

I have been building Rails for a long time and (recently) AngularJS for the last 3 months. It's my first attempt with WebSockets and I am creating a test project with this module https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket. I want to be able to view Twitter or Weather data for example from public APIs.

I have followed the instructions and scaffolded a new project with yeoman but I am missing a part: How do you connect the RESTful GET data with the "ws:" websocket stream ? Do I need a server of some sort ?

EDIT: I'll rephrase my question: What do I need in order to get http data via websockets ? Do I need to build a websockets server in my backend ?

Comment: If your goal is to have a server poll a Twitter end point and then send a websocket message to your angular app, then yes, you will need a server.

Comment: @arjabbar can you please give some more details ?

Comment: I responded with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have a server poll a Twitter end point and then send a websocket message to your angular app, then yes, you will need a server.

So you'll need to create an app server somewhere using your favorite language. It doesn't have to be on the same domain or even have to be the same server that serves out your angular app.

Then write some code that hits the Twitter end point you are interested in at whatever interval you desire. Keep in mind though that Twitter could have a limit on the number of requests that you can send during a time period.

Then you could keep track of all the Twitter data that you received before and whenever you get back more data from Twitter, then you can send out a Websocket message with the new data to all your connected Websocket clients.

Whatever language or framework you decide to use to build your server, more than likely there will be a Websocket library that you could use to make things a little easier.

I'm not saying this is the best way to accomplish your goal, but just judging by your original post, this seems like it might be one way of getting stuff done.

The same thing could be accomplished without using Websockets at all though. With this scenario, you're having a server do all the polling and merging of data. You could just have your Angular app (or clients) do all the polling and merging as well.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket protocol is totally different with http(or https)

`RESTful Get` that you want to connect is possible only on http protocol.

And Twitter does not provide websocket interface.